# pip install virtualenvwrapper-powershell not working

Tags: python, powershell, pip, virtualenv

I'm trying to create a virtualenv with powershell but I get the following error for which I have not found a solution:

```
Collecting virtualenvwrapper-powershell
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/40/36d418b950139cd09738c0924066ef340ffd6c43f79f67c6152c56a8a628/virtualenvwrapper-powershell-12.7.8.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\spajd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q84xhg3w\virtualenvwrapper-powershell\setup.py", line 76
        TOKEN_READ = 0x00020000L | 0x0008
                               ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me!

Comment: what are you typing to create a virtualenv? you what to create virtualenv or you what to install it ? in error say's that you want to install it.. what are you typing

Comment: pip install virtualenvwrapper-powershell

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `0x00020000L` is Python2-only:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Nov 24 2017, 17:33:09) 
>>> 0x00020000L
131072L

$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
>>> 0x00020000L
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    0x00020000L
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code is obviously not for Python3.

Answer (score 0):

The module [virtualenvwrapper-powershell](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper-powershell/#history) is a little bit outdated since 2012. The error could be due to the newer `pip` version installed in your machine. You might have to [downgrade your pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773109/how-to-downgrade-the-installed-version-of-pip-on-windows) in order for that module to be installed.