# How to configure interpreter in PyCharm after downgrading python 3.8 to 3.7 on windows?

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to downgrade my python to 3.7 because the whl that i want to install(https://github.com/intxcc/pyaudio_portaudio/releases) only supports python 3.7.
I tried uninstalling python 3.8 and installing 3.7.But now i can't configure the interpreter in pycharm.
Anyone can help with that?
Thanks[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to downgrade the installed version of 'pip' on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773109/how-to-downgrade-the-installed-version-of-pip-on-windows)

Comment: Sounds like you downgraded fine. Please be more specific about Pycharm issues

Comment: i can't use pip because it says No Python at 'C:\Users\palom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe'

Comment: There must be a path to the Python directory on your computer. Just edit that in settings.

Comment: For the future: Use something like conda or venvs to have automatic compatability checking

Comment: I changed the title, because the question is really about PyCharm cofiguration. Downgrade was not necessary as it's OK to have multiple versions. See my answer below.

Comment: By the way, those of you that down-voted this question - it would be nice to explain why you downvoted. Especially with new members, you should give the asker the chance to edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't need to uninstall Python 3.8, because PyCharm supports multiple interpreters. You can have some project using 3.7 and others using 3.8.

To set the interpreter for a specific project, click `File` and select `Settings` from the drop down.

In the `settings` popup, find your project and then `Project Interpreter` :

[image: Project interpreter in Settings]

Click on the drop-down arrow circled in red, and you will get a list of interpreters available to choose from.

If none of them are correct ones, select `Show all`, and a new popup with the name `Project Interpreters` appears on top, listing more interpreters.

If none of those is correct one, click on the `+` in the upper right corner of the `Project Interpreters`, and get `Add Python Interpreter` popup.

It's a good idea to use virtual environments. If you already have a virtual environment inside your project, either delete it or create a new one with a different name (the default name is `<your project path>/venv`). For example, instead of `venv`, use `venv37`.

[image: Add Project Interpreter]

The drop-down arrow I circled in green will show all the interpreters that PyCharm knows about.

If the new one doesn't show, click on `...` (circled in blue), and locate the newly installed interpreter in the file system. Then click `OK` to close  `Add Python Interpreter` popup, and get back to `Project Interpreters`.

The new virtual environment will show on that list. Select it and click `OK`.

Now you should be back in Settings. Click `Apply` and then `OK`.

From now on, this PyCharm project will be using the new interpreter.