# Speed up loop Matplotlib

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I have to speed up the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,25))
subplots = (4,1)
n_panels = subplots[0] * subplots[1]

# plot medie primo modello
ax = fig.add_subplot(subplots[0], subplots[1], 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines() 

ds[var].plot(vmin=b, vmax=a, cmap='coolwarm', ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Dataset 1: mean')

# plot medie secondo modello
bx = fig.add_subplot(subplots[0], subplots[1], 2, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
bx.coastlines()

ds2[var].plot(vmin=b, vmax=a, cmap='coolwarm', ax=bx)
bx.set_title('Dataset 2: mean')

# plot anomalie assolute modelli
cx = fig.add_subplot(subplots[0], subplots[1], 3, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
cx.coastlines()

anom.plot(vmin=anom.min(), vmax=anom.max(), cmap='coolwarm')
cx.set_title('Absolute anomalies')

# plot anomalie assolute modelli
dx = fig.add_subplot(subplots[0], subplots[1], 4, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
dx.coastlines()

anom2.plot(vmin=anom2.min(), vmax=anom2.max(), cmap='coolwarm')
dx.set_title('Relative anomalies')
```

I don't know why this code it took only few seconds to perform some days ago and now it takes more than 5 minutes (I guess due to issues with updating Matplotlib and Cartopy). 'ds[var]' represents temperature in netcdf datasets and 'anom' represents anomalies computed between two datasets 'ds' and 'ds2'. 
Thank you for helping me!

Comment: if youre right you could downgrade matplotlib and cartopy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773109/how-to-downgrade-the-installed-version-of-pip-on-windows

Comment: I've already downgraded Matplotlib to 2.2.2 version, but cartopy is version 0.16.0 and cannot downgrade or upgrade it.