# pip doesn't work after upgrade on Python 3.4 (Windows 10). How to downgrade?

Tags: python, pip, python-3.4

I upgraded pip on Python 3.4 to last version (20.1.1) and new pip doesn't work with message

```
RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required
```

How to return back old version of pip?

I can't upgrade Python to 3.5 version or more

I can't use a new pip to install old version - my new pip doesn't work at all

Is there any way to uninstall pip?

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773109/how-to-downgrade-the-installed-version-of-pip-on-windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to downgrade the installed version of 'pip' on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773109/how-to-downgrade-the-installed-version-of-pip-on-windows)

Comment: No, this doesn't work in my case. They use new pip to install old version but my new pin doesn't work at all.

Comment: have a look at [the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) - you could download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and use e.g. `python get-pip.py pip==9.0.3`

Comment: @MrFuppes Just tried  `RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required` again - looks like get-pip.py use previous version of pip.

Comment: Try `python -m ensurepip --upgrade`. See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ensurepip.html

Comment: @phd Tried `python -m ensurepip --upgrade`. Doesn't work `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\program files (x86)\python34\lib\site-packages` looks like `ensurepip` think that all ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. MrFuppes gave good advice but it doesn't work because of `get-pip.py` file is intended for last version of pip (version 20.1.1). If download old version of this file - all works. Version of pip that goes with Python 3.4 is version 7.1.2.

So go to https://bootstrap.pypa.io/3.2/ and download `get-pip.py` file. This is an old version of pip (7.1.2). Go to folder where `get-pip.py` is located and run:

```
python get-pip.py pip==7.1.2
```

This uninstall your current version of pip (20.1.1) and setup old version (7.1.2).

Actually this site https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ has some versions of pip - (7.1.2), (9.0.3), (10.0.1), (19.1.1) and (20.1.1) today. I think that other versions before 20.1.1 should work too. Since version 19.1 of pip is last that support Python 3.4.