# pip upgrade regret how to fix it please

Tags: python, pip

Upgraded pip and now I can't install any python packages. this is the error i get when i try
pip install pandas

I used to get already installed, etc.**

now i get this:

```
PS C:\Users\Jacque Quinn Trahan> pip install pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jacque quinn trahan\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\jacque quinn trahan\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Jacque Quinn Trahan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\jacque quinn trahan\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\users\jacque quinn trahan\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\users\jacque quinn trahan\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "c:\users\jacque quinn trahan\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.hashes import STRONG_HASHES
  File "c:\users\jacque quinn trahan\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\hashes.py", line 2, in <module>
    from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, BinaryIO, Dict, Iterator, List, NoReturn
ImportError: cannot import name 'NoReturn'
PS C:\Users\Jacque Quinn Trahan>
```

Comment: This issue is similar: https://github.com/psf/black/issues/1666. What version of pip and python are you using? It seems upgrading python might fix it.

Comment: I want to do that but I am currently going through two books "automat the boring stuff" and "learn python 3 the hard way" which both need ver 3.6 for python. I'm trying to find a way to downgrade my pip but all i get is how to upgrade python models/pip itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773109/how-to-downgrade-the-installed-version-of-pip-on-windows maybe this? In the worst case, you could uninstall python/pip and reinstall. You could also create a conda or virtualenv environment, and have whatever versions of python/pip/etc you need there.

Comment: Nope. Uninstall python and reinstalled it and same thing.  I can't do any module downloads but can still use the ones i had already download.....Yet all this started due to my home computer can't use pandas but my piece of crap work computer can.

Comment: try this `python -m pip install pip==x.x.x` or `pip install pip==20.1.1`, I have 20.1.1 in my env.

Comment: i did this and the same exact error pops up. python -m pip install pip==9.0.1 all the extra stuff above with the last line reading: ImportError: cannot import name 'NoReturn'

Comment: Just tried pip install pip==20.1.1 and same error.

Comment: So I fixed it but it was not ideal. Luckily I had set a restore point on my computer two days ago and just restored the older version deleted the pip upgrade. But also lost all work i did not upload to my google/one drives(Very little)

Only other way online that I saw this  fixed was having to upgrade python to the newsiest version. Even then I did not see a way to downgrade pip successfully. I don't like it